Remove IP_Address from Tibble
i want to remove the IP_Address from tibble and overwrite the existing tibble with a version that excludes the IP_address?
(name of the data file) then select(IP_address)
I have saved a data file and renamed it but now I want to remove the IP_address from tibble
